# datatable.js fnServerParams is not working with parameterized array data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I am using `datatable.js` with MVC4 web application. I am try to pass array data in `fnServerParams`.

Here I create a array object called `array` to passing data to server side.

Please see my code below:

```
function GetTaxInvoices(IsInital, TaxInvoiceIds) {

    alert("message : IsInital :- " + IsInital + " , TaxInvoiceIds :- " + TaxInvoiceIds);

    var elementName = "#tblCreatedTaxInvoices";

    ClearData(dtTable2);

    var array = [51, 52];

    ajaxUrl = (IsInital) ? null : '@Url.Action("GetCreatedTaxInvoices", "Invoice")';

    dtTable2 = $(elementName).dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        sAjaxSource: ajaxUrl,
        traditional: true,
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push(
                            { "name": "TaxInvoiceIds", "value": array }
            );
        },
        aoColumns: [
            { sTitle: "Id", bSortable: false, bVisible: false, },
            { sTitle: "PoBox Number", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Email", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Owner", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "General Tax", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Consumption Tax", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Due Amount", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Date", bSortable: false, },
            { sTitle: "Detailes", bSortable: false, },
        ],
    });

}
```

But it always shows null.

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the body of the request?

Comment: Sure... Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Actually i try to pass a array in my Controller action. I already use '$.makeArray' but it's not working.

Comment: What happens if you change `long[] TaxInvoiceIds` to `string[] TaxInvoiceIds` or even just `string TaxInvoiceIds`?

Comment: Yes, it's working when i replace the 'string[] ' with 'string' , But you mean it's not possible to use a array ?

Comment: I don't think v1.9 supports it 'as-is', but I could be wrong. You could pass the comma-separated list as a string and convert it back to a list in `GetCreatedTaxInvoices`.  Another option is to loop over the array in `fnServerParams` and call `aoData.push` on each element.

Comment: Thank you for your valueable reply. I will use comm-seperated list instead of array. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 aoData.push(
      { "name": "TaxInvoiceIds[]", "value": array }
 );
```

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/a3f57e4

or this:
http://www.justinmichaels.net/custom-serverside-filtering-with-jquery-datables-and-asp-net-mvc3 (I am using this way).